Basic open set of the weak topology on a normed space
Let $X$ be a normed space. The weak topology on $X$ is generated by all maps $f\in X^{*}$. A subbasic open set of this topology is of the form
$$
\{x\in X: |f(x) - c| < r\}
$$
for some $f\in X^*$, $c\in F$ and $r > 0$. I read somewhere that any subbasic open set can also be written as
$$
\{x\in X: |f(x)| < r\}
$$
for some $f\in X^*$ and $r > 0$ but no further explanations were given.
Could anyone help me understand it? Thank you!
Edit: I understand that the translation map is a homeomorphism so $f^{-1}(B(c,r))$ = $T\circ f(B(0,r))$ for some translation operator $T$. But $T\circ f$ is not necessarily a linear map right, so $T\circ f$ might not belong to $X^{*}$.
Update: Apparently I remembered wrongly cuz not every weakly open set contains $0$...

A subbasis $S$ in a topological space is a collection of open sets such that all open sets are unions of intersections of finite intersections of members of $S$.
That's clearly not the case for the sets $\{x \in X: |f(x)| < r\}$: all these sets contain $0$, so the unions of their intersections also contains $0$, but not every open set contains $0$.  So this is not a subbasis for the weak topology.  What it is, instead, is a neighbourhood subbasis of $0$ for the weak topology, i.e. a collection $S$ of weak neighbourhoods of $0$ such that a set is a weak neighbourhood of $0$ iff it contains the intersection of finitely many members of $S$.

Thank you! @RobertIsrael Then is it true that every subbasic open set is a translation of the set ${x\in X: |f(x)| < r}$, and every basic open set is a translation of the set $\bigcap_{i = 1}^n{x\in X: |f_i(x)| < r_i}$ $($translation in the sense of v + S for the set $S)$?

Yes, it is true.

Thank you! @RobertIsrael
